# Codeigniter curl cron job and sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cron

I'm using CodeIgniter and I have cron jobs run with curl, for example:

```
0,30 * * * * curl --silent http://example.com/cron/1
```

I also store sessions in the database

But session also storing curl in the database.

How to avoid this?

The server is running on Centos 6

Or I can make call to cron without curl to not use session?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest way to get codeigniter working under cron job,

You can use curl in cron jobs to execute or run the codeigniter in cron jobs Example:

- - - - - /usr/bin/curl https://www.domain.com/controller/function

I used this way, but I did not get curl in DB.